# Creating columns based on multiple, semi-complex filtering conditions within R (dplyr, stringr, lubridate)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate, stringr

I have a dataset, df

```
 Read      Box       ID      Time                            
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:00:01 AM
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:00:02 AM             
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:00:03 AM            
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:02:59 AM             
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:03:00 AM
 F                           10/1/2019 9:05:00 AM
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:06:00 AM             
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:06:02 AM             
 T         in                10/1/2019 9:07:00 AM
 T         in                10/1/2019 9:07:02 AM
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:07:04 AM
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:07:05 AM             
 T         out               10/1/2019 9:07:06 AM             
 T         out    hello      10/1/2019 9:07:08 AM
 F         in                10/1/2019 9:08:10 AM
 F         in                10/1/2019 9:08:11 AM
 T         draft             10/2/2019 10:00:00 AM
 T         draft             10/2/2019 10:00:05 AM
 T         draft             10/2/2019 10:00:20 AM
 T         draft             10/2/2019 10:00:25 AM
 T         draft             10/2/2019 10:02:00 AM
 T         draft             10/2/2019 10:02:20 AM
```

Based on certain conditions within this dataset, I would like to create a starttime column and an endtime column.

I would like to create a 'starttime' when the following occurs: 
Read == "T", Box == "out" OR Box == "draft", and ID == ""

I would like to create an "endtime" when the following occurs:
Read == "T", Box == "out" OR Box == "draft", and ID == ""  and when the gap in between the desired conditions is less than 30 seconds.

When the first instance of this condition occurs, a starttime will be generated. For example for this dataset, the starttime will be 10/1/2019 9:00:01 AM since this is where we see the desired conditions Read  = T, Box = "out" or Box == "draft" and ID = ""

However, the moment when any one of these conditions is not true, OR if the time in between timestamps exceeds 30 seconds an endtime will be created. So for instance, a starttime is created at row 17 at:
 10/2/2019 10:00:00 AM and an endtime will be created at row 20 at: 10/2/2019 10:00:25 AM

The next starttime will be created at: 10/2/2019 10:02:00 AM, due to the time in between timestamps exceeding 30 seconds.
I am not sure if I need to incorporate a thresh within this code to satisfy this? I am just not sure how to implement this.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
  starttime                    endtime                     duration

  10/1/2019 9:00:01 AM        10/1/2019 9:03:00 AM         179 secs
  10/1/2019 9:06:00 AM        10/1/2019 9:06:02 AM         2 secs
  10/1/2019 9:07:05 AM        10/1/2019 9:07:06 AM         1 secs
  10/2/2019 10:00:00 AM       10/2/2019 10:00:25 AM        25 secs
  10/2/2019 10:02:00 AM       10/2/2019 10:02:20 AM        20 secs
```

dput:

```
  structure(list(Read = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Box = structure(c(4L, 4L, 
  4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "draft", "in", "out"), class = "factor"), 
  ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
  "hello"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(1:22, .Label = c("10/1/2019 9:00:01 AM", 
  "10/1/2019 9:00:02 AM", "10/1/2019 9:00:03 AM", "10/1/2019 9:02:59 AM", 
  "10/1/2019 9:03:00 AM", "10/1/2019 9:05:00 AM", "10/1/2019 9:06:00 AM", 
  "10/1/2019 9:06:02 AM", "10/1/2019 9:07:00 AM", "10/1/2019 9:07:02 AM", 
  "10/1/2019 9:07:04 AM", "10/1/2019 9:07:05 AM", "10/1/2019 9:07:06 AM", 
  "10/1/2019 9:07:08 AM", "10/1/2019 9:08:10 AM", "10/1/2019 9:08:11 AM", 
  "10/2/2019 10:00:00 AM", "10/2/2019 10:00:05 AM", "10/2/2019 10:00:20 AM", 
  "10/2/2019 10:00:25 AM", "10/2/2019 10:02:00 AM", "10/2/2019 10:02:20 AM"
   ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -22L))
```

I would like to also incorporate the Box == "draft" as well as the >30 second thresh within this code

```
  library(dplyr)



  Thresh <- 30  (seconds)


  df1<-df %>%
  mutate(Time = lubridate::mdy_hms(Time), 
     cond = Read == "True" & Box == "out"|Box == "draft" & ID == "" , 
     grp = cumsum(!cond)) %>%
  filter(cond) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(starttime = first(Time), 
        endtime = last(Time), 
        duration = difftime(endtime, starttime, units = "secs")) %>%
  select(-grp)
```

Comment: I can't quite grasp your logic.If 09:02:59 is an end time because more than 30 seconds have passed since the last time stamp, why is 10:00:25 an end time? There seems to be an inconsistency about how you have applied the rules here. If more than 30 seconds have passed since the last time stamp, do you start a new duration, or is this where you end the last duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be inconsistency about how the rules are applied in the example given in the question. It is not clear whether, when 30 seconds have passed since last timestamp, this should mark the beginning of a new period or the end of the previous period. Both are used in the example.

I will assume a new period starts if 30 seconds have elapsed, which means the last valid time stamp *prior* to this marks the end of the previous period.

This method works without loops. It splits the times into consecutive runs of "valid" times (i.e. those meeting the criteria), then further splits these if there are gaps of more than 30 seconds. It then simply extracts the minimum and maximum time in each sub group.

```r
library(lubridate)

df$Time <- dmy_hms(df$Time)
valid   <- df$Read == TRUE & df$ID == "" & (df$Box == "out" | df$Box == "draft")
groups  <- rep(seq_along(rle(valid)$lengths), rle(valid)$lengths)
dflist  <- lapply(split(df[valid, ], groups[valid]), function(x) {
                    y <- as.numeric(difftime(x$Time, lag(x$Time)))
                    split(x, cumsum(is.na(y) | y > 30))
                  })

start   <- lapply(dflist, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) as.character(min(y$Time))))
end     <- lapply(dflist, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) as.character(max(y$Time))))
start   <- as.POSIXct(unlist(start))
end     <- as.POSIXct(unlist(end))

data.frame(start = start, end = end, duration = difftime(end, start))
#>                   start                 end duration
#> 1.0 2019-01-10 09:00:01 2019-01-10 09:03:00 179 secs
#> 3.0 2019-01-10 09:06:00 2019-01-10 09:06:02   2 secs
#> 5.0 2019-01-10 09:07:04 2019-01-10 09:07:06   2 secs
#> 7.0 2019-02-10 10:00:00 2019-02-10 10:02:20 140 secs
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Allen let me try this out tomorrow. To answer your question, the reason I was saying that 10:00:25 is an endtime, because, the next timestamp is 10:02:00 and that exceeds 30 seconds. (going from 10:00:25 to 10:02:00 exceeds the 30 second point, and so it should break between these times) Furthermore, my apologies, 9:03:00 should be the end time. The next time stamp would be: 9:00:00 - 9:00:02 Is there a way your code can be adjusted before I try? Thank you this has helped me a lot. ( I was trying to say, that it 'splits' when the times in between exceed 30 seconds)

Comment: @TanishaHudson I think if you check the numbers and the logic of the code I have posted, it does exactly what you are describing. If not, please describe exactly what the problem is with the results and why they don't match your desired output

Comment: hi @Allan Can you look at my most recent question please?